# Column position out of range, ResultSet is '0'

Tags: java, sql

Everything just worked don't know what I did ,but I keep getting the error when wanting to UPDATE information in my SQL database. Error : The column position '1' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'

```
try
{
     String em = EmailField.getText();
     String na = NameField.getText();
     String su = SurnameField.getText();
     String i = IDField.getText();
     String ce = CellField.getText();

     String query2 = "UPDATE LouwDataBase.Table1Test "
                    + "SET Email = "+"'"+em+"'"+" , "
                    + "Name = "+"'"+na+"'"+" , "
                    + "Surname = "+"'"+su+"'"+" , "
                    + "ID = "+"'"+i+"'"+" , "
                    + "Cell = "+"'"+ce+"'"
                    + " WHERE Email = "+"'"+UserEmailID+"'";

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase", "LouwDataBase", "1234");
      stat = conn.createStatement();

      try (Connection conn = this.connect();
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query2)) 
      {
            pstmt.setString(1, em);
            pstmt.setString(3, na);
            pstmt.setString(4, su);
            pstmt.setString(5, i);
            pstmt.setString(6, ce);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
       } 
       catch (SQLException e) 
       {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
}
```

Comment: Your query has no parameters, yet you are setting values to parameters.

Comment: Where should I add parameters?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: In place of your string concatenations. Like "Where Email = ?" instead of all of the concats.

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), I think you need to have question marks in the query and then use `pstmt.setString()`.

```
try {
  String em = EmailField.getText();
  String na = NameField.getText();
  String su = SurnameField.getText();
  String i = IDField.getText();
  String ce = CellField.getText();

  String query2 = "UPDATE LouwDataBase.Table1Test "
                 + "SET Email = ?, "
                 + "Name = ?, "
                 + "Surname = ?, "
                 + "ID = ?, "
                 + "Cell = ?"
                 + " WHERE Email = ?";

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase", "LouwDataBase", "1234");
  stat = conn.createStatement();

  try (Connection conn = this.connect();
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query2)) {
      pstmt.setString(1, em);
      pstmt.setString(3, na);
      pstmt.setString(4, su);
      pstmt.setString(5, i);
      pstmt.setString(6, ce);
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
   } 
   catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
}
```